Maven install destroys lombok Builder
Im trying to make a Website which stores files.
By now i have a springboot rest-server, a simple frontend, a database that stores just ur name and the url of the file, and a MinIO that should store the file itself.
Everything works fine until u try to do a maven install. Somehow the Maven install deletes the DocumentEntityBuilder and the DocumentDtoBuilder which always throws an error.
On a clean build the target directory clearly shows that lombok annotations worked properly and the entity and dto classes have an associated builder. However when running Maven install or compile it fails with the "cannot find symbol" error and the builder is deleted.
I have tried building and rebuilding the project after a maven clean which didn't work.
I have tried invalidating IDE cache and reloading the project from files.
I have tried a clean download from the github repository.
I have tried reworking the pom.xml to check for annotations and different versions of lombok.
I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling lombok.
I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2024.3
pom.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>at.fhtw</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>rest</name>
    <description>rest</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.0.Final</version> <!-- Ensure the version is compatible with your setup -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version> <!-- Required for expression language support -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.minio</groupId>
            <artifactId>minio</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.2</version> <!-- Prüfe die neueste Version -->
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

target after clean and build
target after install
The whole project is available on GitHub
https://github.com/SFSDeco/FHTW_SWKOM_Project
If anybody has any ideas please help

Which version of lombok is being used here? you can run java -jar lombok.jar version to find out (so, find the one maven uses / use -v to tell maven to tell you where it stored it, and run it).

@rzwitserloot 1.18.36

Allright, that eliminates one explanation.

<exclude><groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId><artifactId>lombok</artifactId></exclude> looks suspicious.

Based on the used spring boot version (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/3.3.4/spring-boot-dependencies-3.3.4.pom)  the version must be 1.18.34... also why not using the most recent SB version (3.3.5) also why overwriting the hibernate validator version? (use the one which is provided by SB) and why using an ancient old mockito version... SB offers more recent one...

@talexmovedtoCodidact doesnt matter if its there or not the error is still the same, so shouldnt be the problem

I just have similar problem with java 23. What version do you use? I solved it by switching to previous version.

@talexmovedtoCodidact same version but we found the error

The Problem was solved by editing the pom.xml build to the following code
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.34</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

